# How to convert a string into date in order to manipulate database

Tags: sql, delphi-7, ado

I am new to coding and have a project for school. 
I am trying to convert a string to a date in order to update/delete records from database but it constantly gives me a `Data type mismatch in criteria expression` error. The field in the database(date booked) is validated as a date and I am trying to convert my string input to a date format and then delete the entire record of it from my database.

```
   sdelete:= combobox.text;  //shows options of dates
    Year := StrToInt(Copy(sdelete, 1, 4));
    Month := StrToInt(Copy(sdelete, 6, 2));
    day := StrToInt(Copy(sdelete, 9,2));
    date := EncodeDate(Year, Month,Day);
 end;//Converting to date format

`ADOdelete.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM [scout] WHERE ([Password] =  
"'+Sscout+'"AND [date booked] ="'+FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd',Date)+'")';`
   ADOdelete.Open;
   ADOdelete.Close;
ADOdelete.SQL.Text:= 'Delete from [scout] WHERE ([date booked] 
     ="'+FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd',Date)+'"AND [password]="'+sscout+'")';
   ADOdelete.ExecSQL;
   ADOdelete.Free;`
```

`[Scout]` is the table name
and Sscout is a private variable that has the password saved within.
the combobox is populated by amounts in the database([date booked]) and displays as such `yyyy/mm/dd`
and i have the following variables

```
var       sdelete:string;
          Day, Month, Year: Word;
          date:Tdatetime;
```

Thank You.

Comment: Do not fill in values with string concatenation: then you are vulnerable to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Find out how to use parameters in your queries - that will also do the correct conversion of dates and other types of values.

Comment: Try a more widely recognized format yyyy-mm-dd but you really should move away from the way you are preparing the sql. Note the format is a hunch not a certainty. It will differ by dbms settings and which dbms it is.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [parameterized queries](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries) instead. Let the DB driver handle escaping and formatting for you. For example:

```
var
  sDelete: string;
  dtBooked: TDate;
  fmt: TFormatSettings;
begin
  sDelete := ComboBox.Text; //shows options of dates

  fmt := TFormatSettings.Create;
  fmt.DateSeparator := '/'; // or '-' depending on your needs...
  fmt.ShortDateFormat := 'yyyy/mm/dd';
  dtBooked := StrToDate(sDelete, fmt);

  ADOdelete.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM [scout] WHERE ([Password] = :password AND [date booked] = :booked)';
  ADOdelete.Parameters.ParamByName('password').Value := sScout;
  ADOdelete.Parameters.ParamByName('booked').Value := dtBooked;
  ADOdelete.Open;
  ...
  ADOdelete.SQL.Text := 'Delete from [scout] WHERE ([date booked] = :booked AND [password] = :password)';
  ADOdelete.Parameters.ParamByName('booked').Value := dtBooked;
  ADOdelete.Parameters.ParamByName('password').Value := sScout;
  ADOdelete.ExecSQL;
  ...
end;
```